# how to run socket.io and now.js without any issue?

Tags: socket.io, nowjs-sockets

**I'm trying to run an application which uses socket.io for some functionality and nowjs for other some functionality?When i run application both the socket.io keep on clashing. please suggest what i have to do?**

***chat module***

```
var io = require('socket.io');
var users = {};
exports.initialize = function(server){
       io= io.listen(server,{ log: false });

        io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {


            socket.on('send message', function(data){
                io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('message', socket.user, data);
            });



            socket.on('messageandsender', function(user){
                var rcvr = user.receiver;
                var sndr = user.sender; 
                io.sockets.emit('msgandreceiver',{'message': user.msg, 'rvr': rcvr, 'sndr': sndr});
            });         


            socket.on('disconnect', function(){
                    delete users[socket.user];
                io.sockets.emit('update',users);
                if(socket.user != undefined)
                socket.broadcast.emit('info', 'SERVER', socket.user + ' has gone offline');
                socket.leave(socket.room);
            });
        });
    };
```

***paint module***

```
var nowjs = require("now");
exports.startnow = function(server){
var everyone = nowjs.initialize(server);
nowjs.on("connect", function () {
    console.log("Joined: " + this.user.clientId);
nowjs.on("disconnect", function () {
    console.log("Left: " + this.user.clientId);
    nowjs.getClient(this.user.clientId,function(){
        console.log(this.now.name);
    });
    updateList();
});

everyone.now.distributeMessage = function (message) {
    everyone.now.processIncomingChatMessage(this.now.name, message);
};

everyone.now.distributePaintCommand = function (paintCommand) {
    everyone.exclude(this.user.clientId).now.processPaintCommand(paintCommand);
};

everyone.now.setName = function(){
    userlist.push(this.now.name);
    console.log(userlist);
    everyone.now.updateUserList(userlist);
};

var userlist = [];

updateList = function(){
    userlist = [];
    everyone.getUsers(function (users) {
        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
            nowjs.getClient(users[i],function(){
                console.log(this.now.name);
                userlist.push(this.now.name);
            });
        }
    });
};

everyone.now.getUserList = function() {
    this.now.updateUserList(userlist);
};

});

};
```

***in server.js***

```
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
});
chat.initialize(server);
paint.startnow(server);
```

**I've added paint model in this case both the sockets from paint and chat module clashes giving following connection warning several times.but unable to connect but when i comment one either chat or paint it works fine**

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/1/websocket/6gMr-tmuaA0kJnNQrIQz' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established. socket.io.js:2438
```

Comment: Post your code and state the error then we might be able to help you

Comment: check out code how can i fix this issue

Comment: This might be due to the Asynchronous nature of Node.js. Have you tried running this by putting all of this code in server.js file?

Comment: yeah tried same issue.I’m thinking weather nowjs and socket.io both trying to get same port which giving rise to this issue.i didn't get exactly what went wrong

Comment: Yeah you're right. But It seems that nowjs is not in active development since a long time so you should look for other alternatives

Comment: ok I'll trying to use socket.io for same process need to figure out how to do it.thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't run both thing simultaneously because both try to require socket @ same port try nginx for node app